# awk: canonical way to reference a field by name (first line as header)

Tags: awk

I often experience this kind of situation: initially my data looks like this:

```
$ cat data.csv
id name age
0 Mark 20
1 Robert 35
2 John 15
```

Given that I want to access the `age` field, I write my `awk` script like this:

```
$ awk '{ print $3; /* print age */ }' data.csv                                                                          
age
20
35
15
```

Then, eventually, the columns order got changed. For example, `surname` is inserted between `name` and `age`, so that now `age` is shifted to the 4th position:

```
$ cat data.csv                                                                                                              
id name surname age
0 Mark Ross 20
1 Robert Green 35
2 John Doe 15
```

If I run my script again, I obviously get the wrong output:

```
$ awk '{ print $3; /* print age */ }' data.csv                                                                              
surname
Ross
Green
Doe
```

To avoid this issue I use to reference the fields by name using this bit of code:

```
$ awk 'NR == 1 { split($0, keys) }; { for (i=1; i<=length(keys); i++) { f[keys[i]]=$i }; print f["age"]; /* print age */ }' data.csv
age
20
35
15
```

This works fine and allows me to reference any fields by name, such as `f["id"]`, `f["name"]` etc. as desired.

What I don't like here is that the script looks hackish and verbose. I have the feeling that I'm missing out a native function or a more straightforward way to achieve something similar.

Does `awk` offer a canonical way to reference fields by name, using the first line as a header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what is canonical but you can avoid a lot of unnecessary copying.

From your code:

```
# why split again? we already have $1..$NF
NR == 1 { split($0, keys) }
{
    # why do this on every line of input?
    for (i=1; i<=length(keys); i++){ f[keys[i]]=$i }

    print f["age"]; /* print age */
}
```

to:

```
NR==1 { while (i++ < NF) f[$i]=i }

{ print $f["age"] }
#       ^
```

Note: I have tried to make the first-line pattern/action as concise as possible to address your verbosity concern but the more straightforward `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` is nearly as short and will be more maintainable than this `while`, and without the potential gotcha if `i` has already been used.

Comment: "as concise as possible ..." -- I'd recommend you don't. If you're trying to teach someone a technique, keep it simple and just show the straightforward maintainable code. That will save you from writing that last paragraph.

Comment: @glennjackman agreed, and I likely will in future (or swap them around). in my defense, I was aiming to address the "too verbose" part of the question (I actually first answered with a for but this while is 6% shorter (and 15% shorter than the "canonical" for)

Answer (score 3):

Setup:

```
$ head data.?.csv
==> data.1.csv <==
id name age
0 Mark 20
1 Robert 35
2 John 15

==> data.2.csv <==
id name surname age
0 Mark Ross 20
1 Robert Green 35
2 John Doe 15
```

I'd convert the `keys[]` array to an associative array (column headers/names are the keys of the associative array), eg:

```
colname='age'

for fname in data.1.csv data.2.csv
do
    echo "########## file: ${fname}"

    awk -v cname="${colname}" '
    FNR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                 keys[$i]=i
           }
           { print $(keys[cname]) }
    ' "${fname}"
done
```

This generates:

```
########## file: data.1.csv
age
20
35
15
########## file: data.2.csv
age
20
35
15
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not strictly limited to GNU `AWK` then you might exploit GNU `datamash` as follows, let `data.csv` content be

```
id name age
0 Mark 20
1 Robert 35
2 John 15
```

then

```
datamash --header-in --field-separator=' ' cut age < data.csv
```

gives output

```
20
35
15
```

Explanation: `--header-in` informs that first line of input is header with names, `--field-separator=' '` that columns are space-sheared, [`cut` is operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Available-Operations.html) `age` is field name.

(tested in GNU datamash 1.7)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the pure-awk standard method. I suggest for this task to use [`miller`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/) toolkit to manipulate tab-delimited files using column names. Below is a one-liner that filters a tab-delimited file (delimiter is specified using `--tsv`) and writes the results to STDOUT together with the header. The header is removed using `tail` and the lines are counted with `wc`.

```
mlr --tsv filter '$colA == "c" && $colB == "water"' file.txt | tail -n +2 | wc -l
```

**SEE ALSO:**

Note that [`miller`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) can be easily installed, for example, using [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html), specifically `miniconda`, like so:

```
conda create --name miller miller
```

Comment: `miller --version` -> `-bash: miller: command not found`, `conda create --name miller miller` -> `-bash: conda: command not found`. I'm using bash 4.4.12 on cygwin.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thank you, I updated the stale links! Note that you have to install `conda` first (follow the link above). *Then* use `conda` to install `miller`. I just verified that I could install `miller` as shown above on macOS Monterey, v12.4. There may be other ways to install `miller`. I simply use `conda` to install many bioinformatics packages, so this is the first thing I tried to get `miller`.

Comment: I'm on cygwin, it doesn't seem to have conda or miller available nor could I find anything about installing on cygwin in the miller installation page. If there is a way to install it on cygwin, it's apparently not easy.

Comment: @EdMorton it's standard with ubuntu. I haven't used Windows for about 5 years. It may be a little heavyweight but could people who are interested just bring up [ubuntu in WSL2](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) if they want to play?

Comment: @jhnc thanks for the suggestion but I'm not going to do that and rewrite my existing tools that call Windows tools from cygwin and vice-versa just to be able to use miller.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Awk

**Function**

```
#!/bin/bash

getcolumns(){
  local OPTIND fname header before after fname
  
  __usage(){
    echo "Usage: ${FUNCNAME[1]} [OPTION]... -c [COLUMN],... [FILE]..."
    echo "Options:"
    echo "  -c <STR,...>   columns to be found"
    echo "  -a <STR>       add string after last column"
    echo "  -b <STR>       add string before first column"
    echo "  -s <STR>       set output delimiter"
    echo "  -d <STR>       set input delimiter"
    echo "  -h             display column header"
    echo "  -n             display filename"
    echo "Example: "
    printf "  %s -d, -s'\\\t' -c name,age file1 file2\n" "${FUNCNAME[1]}"
    exit 1;
  }

  while getopts "a:b:c:d:hns:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        a) after=${OPTARG};;
        b) before=${OPTARG};;
        c) columns=${OPTARG};;
        d) delimiter=${OPTARG};;
        h) header=1;;
        n) fname=1;;
        s) separator=${OPTARG};;
        \?) echo "ERROR: Invalid option -$OPTARG";;
    esac
  done
  
  shift $((OPTIND-1))

  if [ -z "${columns}" ] || [ "${#}" -eq 0 ]; then
    __usage
  fi

  awk -v columns="$columns" \
      -v delimiter="${delimiter:= }" \
      -v separator="${separator:0 }" \
      -v header="$header" \
      -v fname="$fname" \
      -v before="$before" \
      -v after="$after" '
      BEGIN{ FS=delimiter; OFS=separator; split(columns,cols,",") }
      BEGINFILE{
        if(ERRNO){ print "Error: no such file " FILENAME; nextfile }
        if (fname) print "-----" FILENAME "-----"
      } 
      FNR==1{
        delete key; i=0;
        while(i++<NF)keys[$i]=i
        if(! header) next 
      }
      { 
        before ? out=before OFS : out=""
        #out=""
        for (x in cols){
          if(cols[x] in keys != 0 )
            out=sprintf("%s%s%s", out, $(keys[cols[x]]), OFS)
        }
        after ? out=out after : sub(OFS"$","",out)
      }
      out { print out }
  ' "${@}"
}
```

**Usage**

```
Usage: getcolumns [OPTION]... -c [COLUMN],... [FILE]...
Options:
  -c <STR,...>   columns to be found
  -a <STR>       add string after last column
  -b <STR>       add string before first column
  -s <STR>       set output delimiter
  -d <STR>       set input delimiter
  -h             display column header
  -n             display filename
Example: 
  getcolumns -d, -s'\t' -c name,age file1 file2
```

**Files**

```
$ head file[12]
==> file1 <==
id,name,surname,age
0,Mark,Ross,24
1,Robert,Green,45
2,John,Doe,19

==> file2 <==
n,age,foo,name
x,20,111,Kate
x,35,222,Nancy
x,15,333,Jimmy
```

### **Tests**

```
getcolumns -d, -c age file2

20
35
15
```

---

```
getcolumns -d, -s'\t' -c name,age -b "foo" -a "bar baz" file1 file2 

foo     Mark    24      bar baz
foo     Robert  45      bar baz
foo     John    19      bar baz
foo     Kate    20      bar baz
foo     Nancy   35      bar baz
foo     Jimmy   15      bar baz
```